# Отсутствие переноса строки в созданном файле

Tags: javascript, html5

В приложении создается файл:

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');

  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
                                encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<div id = "div_with_text">some<br/>text</div>
<a href = "javascript:download('text.txt', 
                                 document.getElementById('div_with_text')
                                .textContent)"  
   id = "save" style = "margin-bottom:0px;">save file.</a>
```

Однако в полученном таким образом файле отсутствуют переносы строк. Не подскажите, это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: `<br/>` Это `HTML` элемент переноса строки, в тексте за это отвечает `\r\n`

Comment: просто посмотрите что вам возвращает _textContent_

Comment: Можно попробовать сначала в полученной `javascript` строке поменять все `<br>` и затем писать в файл. `str = str.replaceAll("<br />", "\r\n");`

Comment: textContent возвращает мне текст с переносами (вывела через console.log()) , а str = str.replaceAll... ничего не дало((

Comment: Даже наверное что-то на подобии этого `document.getElementById('div_with_text').textContent.replace("<br/>", "\r\n");`

Comment: @LamerXaKer, это ничего не даст, потому что _textContent_ не возвращает теги. Скорее всего просто там стоит один `\r` или `\n` вместо необходимых `\r\n`

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, но тогда можно использовать не _textContent_ а _.innerHTML_

Comment: Огромное СПАСИБО!!!! Все получилось))) text.replace(/\n/g,'\r\n') и text.replace(/\r/g,'\r\n')

Comment: @LamerXaKer Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

`<br/>` Это `HTML` элемент переноса строки, в тексте за это отвечает `\r\n` (может зависеть от системы, win это, *nix или OSX)

Можно попробовать сначала в полученной *javascript* строке поменять все `<br>` на `\r\n` и затем писать в файл.

`str = str.replaceAll("<br/>", "\r\n");`

В вашем случае, это могло бы выглядеть так:

`document.getElementById('div_with_text').innerHTML.replace("<br/>", "\r\n");`

Возможно, после `document.getElementById('div_with_text').textContent` там отображается не `<br/>` а одиночные `\r` или `\n`. Тогда можно попробовать такой вариант:

`document.getElementById('div_with_text').textContent.replace("(\r|\n)", "\r\n");`